Utilisation des expressions du type "quoi/quel/quelle que soit qqch"
Alors que l'expression quoi que ce soit semble être une locution fixe, je suis un peu perturbé par les versions plus spécifiques. Par exemple, est-ce que quoi que soit la raison ou quelle que soit la raison signifient la même chose ? Comprends-je correctement qu'on a besoin d'accord de genre entre quel/quelle et le nom qui suit ? Je suis aussi un peu perturbé par l'ordre différent de l'objet et le verbe dans quoi que ce soit et quoi que soit la raison.
Une poste lié : Regarding the expression “quoi que ce soit”

J'éviterais quoi que soit la raison. A priori, ce n'est pas correct, mais même si ça l'était, tous ces oi et qu ne sonnent pas bien. J'en resterais à quelle que soit la raison, avec accord de quelle avec raison.
Pour ce qui est de l'ordre des mots, on peut envisager quelle que la raison soit, peut-être un peu moins couramment.
